# Как реализовать диалог между 2 пользователями через бота Телеграм

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, aiogram

Как реализовать диалог между 2 пользователями через бота Телеграм Python.
Возможно использование библиотек PyTelegramBotAPI или AioGram.
Нужно чтобы пользователь заходил в бота, писал сообщение и оно отправлялось другому пользователю в чат бота. То есть, обычный чат, но с посредником в виде бота.
Если можно, то пример реализации или кода. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В самом начале придется получить и прописать в коде chat_id обоих собеседников, а дальше довольно просто.

```
user1_chat_id = "chat_id"
user2_chat_id = "chat_id"

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def messanger(message):
    if message.from_user.chat_id == user1_chat_id:
        bot.send_message(user2_chat_id, message.text)
    else:
        bot.send_message(user1_chat_id, message.text)
```

Это что касается только текстовых сообщений, но можно тоже самое для остальных видов сообщений сделать

Comment: А как их отличить от команд, чтобы команды не отправлялись человеку, а исполнялись?

Comment: @Антон прописывается вот такой декоратор @bot.message_handler(commands=["some_command"]) и когда отправишь в боте эту команду /some_command, она выполнится